# jQuery touchmove not registering in chrome emulator

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, touchstart, touchmove

There's been similar questions on how to fire scroll events (mid-scroll) on mobile/tablet. I've used the code provided below but I've yet to get this to work in chrome emulator.

```
$('body').on({
   'touchmove': function(e) {
       console.log($(this).scrollTop()); // Replace this with your code.
    }
});
```

touchstart will log when I scroll with the touch sensor but not touchmove. What am I missing?

Comment: Works fine for me when I have the dev tools properly setup.

Comment: hmm. not working for me or Christian

Comment: Is the page you're testing with long enough to be scrolled?

Comment: FYI, this sometimes fails for me too but hitting F12, then F12 again to turn dev back on works for me

Answer (score 1):

[image]Did you enable the "emulate touch screen"?

check this link in "sensors"
http://www.sitepoint.com/use-mobile-emulation-mode-chrome/

---

Try this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).bind('touchmove', function(e) {
   console.log($(this).scrollTop()); 
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, that article is outdated so the options change but I definitely have emulate mobile AND emulate touch screen selected. Does it work for you?

Comment: no, it doesn't work. which libraries are you using??

Comment: this is not the same code, but it does the same http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents.shtml

Comment: just using jquery. jquery is loaded.

Comment: so the above code worked on my local desktop test case but just won't work in my work dev. it might have to do with bootstrap and the modularity of it all but im not a js expert :/

edit: by bootstrap i mean backbone

Answer (score 0):

I use `bind` and `originalEvent`, which works on real mobile device:

```
    $("html").bind("touchmove", function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
        var x = touch.pageX, y =touch.pageY;
```